# Rearranging variables in a sas dataset- alphabetical order

Tags: sas, retain

I have like 500 columns of dataset, and I want to rearrange all the variables in an alphabetical order. How can I do that in any other way than using retain statement before set statement?

Answer (score 5):

You can generate the list of variable names dynamically, and create a new dataset using `PROC SQL`.

```
proc sql ;
  select name into :VARLIST separated by ', '
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname = 'SASHELP'
    and memname = 'CLASS' 
  order by name ;
quit ;

proc sql ;
  create table ordered as
  select &VARLIST
  from sashelp.class ;
quit ;
```

Comment: Chris this is nice and simple.  Is there a way to make use of `proc modify` to make it more efficient?

Comment: @Rob - I assume you mean `proc datasets` and the modify statement... unfortunately, rearranging columns is not one of the options.

Comment: ah yes I did mean `proc datasets` sorry.  Ok that's good to know, thanks!

Comment: you can replace the second `proc sql` with `data ordered; retain &VARLIST; set sashelp.class; run;`